# Bootstrap columns - align content to the left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align content of the columns to the left.
I am using bootstrap columns and float divs to compare to.
Here is my bootstrap markup:

```
<div class="row no-gutter" style="margin:0;padding:5px 0">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
             <span">
                 Case #
             </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
             <input  easyui-textbox readonly ng-model="caseid" data-options="font_size:'12'"
                     style="height:30px;width:50px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
             <span">
                 Title
             </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
             <input easyui-textbox data-options="validType:'maxLength[128]',required:true,font_size:'11'"
                    ng-model="title" style="height:30px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and floating divs:

CSS:

```
.col-float{
    float:left;
}
.col-float1{
    width: 5%;
}
.col-float3{
    width: 10%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="margin:0;padding:5px 0">                                        
                <div>
                    <div class="col-float col-float1">
                        <span>
                            State
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-float col-float3">
                        <input easyui-combobox ng-model="caseStateList" selectedvalue="casestate"
                               style="width:75px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-float col-float1">
                        Priority
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-float col-float3">
                        <input easyui-combobox ng-model="casePriorityList" selectedvalue="priorityid"
                               style="width:75px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-float col-float1">
                        Assign
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-float col-float3">
                        <input easyui-combobox ng-model="userPrefList" selectedvalue="assignuser" panelHeight="200px" panelWidth="200px"
                               filter="hideDeletedUsers" style="width:130px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible to have upper row content shifted to the left just like in the second?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the spacing between the columns is too large, or only the spacing to the left labels?

Comment: Mostly spacing labels to the left. It also would be nice to make gutters smaller. Thanks

Comment: Then I would use a list-inline and form-inline like this: http://codeply.com/go/Bh75EGKMhC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Bootstrap's Grid System (rows and columns) does not really work that way. The Grid System works more like a table than floating `div`s.

To achieve a similar effect, you may consider using bootstrap's [forms-inline](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) .

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Case # <input type="text"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title
      <input easyui-textbox data-options="validType:'maxLength[128]',required:true,font_size:'11'"
             ng-model="title" style="height:30px;">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

JSBin Example: http://output.jsbin.com/zuyumimaqu

Note that:

> This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.

Which means they would become vertical forms if the viewer's screen width is less than 768px.

Otherwise, you may have to resort to your float div implementation.

Comment: So, if it's a popup with a width less than 768px forms-inline won't work?

Comment: It would become a vertical form instead, part of bootstrap's responsive design.